# Rigify not using weight-paint from armature

Tags: weight-painting

Pretty basic question, but after parenting the armature to the object and weight-painting all the bones, I use the "generate-rig" button and, despite the rig appearing correctly, it´s not parented to the object.  If I parent it again it will weight automatic and I will have to do all the Weight-painting job again.  Is there a simple solution?  Or should I weigh only after creating the rig?

Answer (score 0):

The Metarig is only something like a "Placeholder", it's used only to set the locations of the bones and it has no other relations with the rig, so: yes, you have to weight only after creating the rig.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Josh.  
I just wanted to be sure there was no way to "transfer" the weights, between the Metarig and rig itself.

Comment: Weights are properties of vertices, in relation with a vertex group, so they are stored with the mesh and do not belong to rigs. If a mesh has an armature modifier pointing at a rig and a vertex group has the same name as a deforming bone of the rig, the bone will move the vertices.